# Shannon O'Hannan Public School Puzzle Contest Winner 2019

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

This puzzle won the Shannon O'Hannanan Public School's Puzzle Club contest. As the prize, we are letting the winner type out his puzzle on the Puzzling Stack Exchange for all of you to solve. Our winner is Simon Swive (Grade 6).

The answer to the puzzle is a noun:

```
11 22 33 44
55 66 77 88
99 1010 1111 1212 
1313 1414 1515 1616 
1717 1818 1919 2020 
212121 2222 XY
```

It should be noted that how the groups of numbers are arranged is irrelevant, so long as the spaces are maintained (they can technically be grouped in any way). The grouping chosen was designed to help you solve the puzzle.

It has several accepted synonyms. You can say it in a sentence, like:

"My son is a _________".
or
"Does your little girl have ________?"

Comment: I don't believe that the "decanting-problems" tag is correct. Excellent puzzle for a 6th grade student by the way - welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Comment: done - edited tags

Comment: is the word the same in both blanks or is it pluralized?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that I'm fairly certain that this school does not exist. - see [here](https://nces.ed.gov/ccd/schoolsearch/index.asp?Search=1&InstName=Shannon+O%27Hannan&SchoolID=&Address=&City=&State=&Zip=&Miles=&County=&PhoneAreaCode=&Phone=&DistrictName=&DistrictID=&SchoolType=1&SchoolType=2&SchoolType=3&SchoolType=4&SpecificSchlTypes=all&IncGrade=7&LoGrade=-1&HiGrade=-1)

Comment: Still no one knows the answer?

Comment: @Brandon_J I legit thought this was a real school XD

Comment: @North same, but my detective brain kicked in lol. I still wonder who user56517 is, and why they came up with a fake school, though. Questions, questions....

Answer (score 12):

Is the answer

> *Down Syndrome*? It's the result of having three of chromosome 21.

Comment: No :) but you're on the right track

Comment: So you know the answer? Also, I updated my guess.

Answer (score 4):

Is the answer

> Human?

Because

> all of the numbers are doubled except 21 which is tripled.  The 21st letter is U.  
> XY is the chromosome pattern for a male, or man.
>  Thus... U-man or human

Comment: No, but close... on the right track :)

Comment: @Vranvs how do you know the answer definitively?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> Trisomy 21.

Because

> all the other chromosome numbers appear in pairs, whereas there are three 21s.